# Exporting contour plot into matrix

Tags: matrix, export

I have a 3D contour image from which I have to export the data points in a matrix format.The image is 1024 x 1024 pixels.

[image]

The codes are below:

```
Export[ToFileName[resultsdir, imagename <> "_MatrixPlot.mat"], rest]
```

I have tried exporting into MAT file, but it shows export failed. Can you please recommend someways to export them?

Comment: are you saying you no longer have access to the data used to create the plot?

Comment: @george2079: I can find an empty file exported in MAT format with no data

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to an array first, e.g., with `ImageData`:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "JellyBeans"}]
Export["a.mat", ImageData[img]]
Image[Import["a.mat"]]
```